# Plantear Sucesion de n numeros Fcos yExpo

Tags: c++, c, recursión, fibonacci

Buenos Dias gente de Stack,alguien le comprende como hacer esta funcion que calculo estas series en c o c++?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estaba tratando de implementarlo a con el algoritmo recursivo de factorial, pero aun no se me da la idea clara.

Adjunto mi Codigo hasta el momento

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int Factorial(int n)
{
    if (n < 0) return 0;
    else if (n > 1) return n * Factorial(n - 1);
    return 1;
}


int FCos(int x){
    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){
        cout<<1-pow(x,2)/Factorial(2) + pow(x,4)/Factorial(4)<<endl;
    }
}

int main(){

    FCos(10);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Qué error te sale? Ante la entrada de `FCos` con 10, qué esperas obtener? Te dejo un ejemplo sencillo sobre cómo emplear funciones recursivas en C https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-recursion)

Comment: Debes tener en cuenta que el factorial de un número crece enormemente a medida que el número es mayor, por lo que me parece que solo podrás hacer el cálculo hasta quizá el factorial de 10.

Comment: Pon un ejemplo del cálculo de la secuencia con un número y pon ese resultado aquí para poder verificar si tu calculo es correcto

Comment: Creo que el código del factorial se ve bien. Veo un problema en `for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)`, ya que `x` es la variable en la cual se quiere evaluar la función coseno. Creo que aún falta mejorar la lógica del cálculo de la serie. El ciclo `for` debería ir sumando los términos de uno en uno hasta llegar a una cantidad `n` de términos pedida.